# Google Map location change and show location marker depends upon drop down value selects by user

Tags: google-maps, drop-down-menu, dynamic-loading

I want to show dynamic map location depends upon the drop-down value selected by the user. For an example, if the user selects new york city in the drop-down value means, in google map must show all list of my company location. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the drop-down you should give the specific map link on of company locations as a value if user select a specific city then it switch according to the given link and show the data on the map.
for example :- 
i have search in map shops near me and copy the link
past inside dropdown

Comment: Hi Sanjay Pal, It can understand that logic you're saying, kindly help me with code example or related article URL. So that I can able to catch easier than this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334276/javascript-pass-a-value-from-dropdown-box-to-google-maps-api
with the help of request.getParameter you can get the value from html page
and you can do one more thing put select inside a form tag action represent the specific java class and when you click on option control will  automatically go to the java Servlet  class method and and you can use the link with help of those two method and pass to the Map api.